# Path issues with Ada and GNATStudio

Tags: ada

I have the following code:

```
with Util.Serialise;
package body blah is

      Reader : Util.Serialize.IO.JSON.Parser;
      Mapper : Util.Serialize.Mappers.Processing;
end blah;
```

So the line where `Reader` is defined is fine with the compiler, however on the following I get the error `Mappers not declared in Serialize`.

Both packages are part of the Ada-Util installation, and in fact are in the same directory.

Is this a path issue? Have I used things wrongly? What's going on here?

Answer (score 4):

You need to `with Util.Serialize.Mappers;` as well, if it's a child package.
You should also need a `with Util.Serialize.IO.JSON;`, don't know why you didn't get an error there

Answer (score 4):

Probably `Reader` is considered as correct, because it is hidden by `Mapper` error.

Generally, in Ada you have to give the full package name if you want to have a package visible. Thus, your first two lines should be:

```
with Util.Serialize.IO.JSON;
with Util.Serialize.Mappers;
```

not just

```
with Util.Serialise;
```

In that situation, you enable package `Utils.Serialize`, not the two which you want.